# Integrated Camera not working kernel 5.11.0-37-generic

Tags: 20.04, webcam, camera

I have been several weeks in which the integrated camera does not work for me. It worked before, but suddenly it stopped working sometimes, and now it directly doesn't work anymore.

Here are the output of a some commands to give you more information:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
uname -r
5.11.0-37-generic
```

```bsh
$ cheese

** (cheese:17881): CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed

(cheese:17881): cheese-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:17881): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:17881): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:17881): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:17881): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:17881): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:17881): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:17881): CRITICAL **: 22:02:42.699: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

```
$ guvcview
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L2 interface for /dev/video0
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/gisele/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: Invalid argument
GUVCVIEW (1): Guvcview error
     no video device found

(guvcview:50268): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:26:50.109: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:50268): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:26:50.109: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:31: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(guvcview:50268): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:26:50.109: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:50268): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:26:50.109: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:32: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
```

```
$ sudo lsusb -v | grep Camera
[sudo] password for gisele: 
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1bcf:0b13 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPCA2087 PC Camera
  iProduct                2 SPCA2087 PC Camera
      iFunction               4 PC Camera
      iInterface              4 PC Camera
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i "Camera"
[    2.061452] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[   11.385308] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:2115)
[   11.403237] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input31
```

```
$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 oct 15 22:33 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 oct 15 23:34 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 oct 15 23:34 /dev/video1
```

```
$ lsmod | grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       61440  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              245760  6 v4l2_fwnode,ov8856,videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  5 videodev,ov8856,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

Hope someone can help me.
I've been with this problem for weeks and I can't fix it

Comment: try checking the hardware user privileges in User and Groups administration and also try restoring your bios to defaults